# sidekiq - avoid clearing delayed_until jobs

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have sidekiq running on heroku that does a lot of syncing with user's emails etc.

Every so often, we were getting the following error:

```
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

To counter this, I created a rake task that is executed by the heroku scheduler.

The rake task restarts all the dynos and flushes all the sidekiq jobs from redis with this code:

```
Sidekiq.redis { |r| r.flushall }
```

I have a new requirement whereby users want to schedule certain jobs to run in the future like this:

```
DeliverEmail.delay_until(email.send_time).perform_async(email.id)
```

Am I right in saying that flushall from the above code sample would flush any scheduled jobs that are created?

If that is the case, is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a redis `FLUSHALL` command, it's truncating the entire redis datastore.  This is a  dangerous thing to do and probably not what you want.

It sounds like what you want to do is clear some types of enqueued work, while preserving others.  You will need to flush each queue you are using, most likely just the `default` queue unless you've setup others:

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new('default').clear
```

This will remove the queue within redis, but preserve your scheduled jobs, statistics, and other data within redis.